# Having trouble to setting position of iframe scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I've been attempting to set the position of an iframe scrollbar. The scrollbar appears to move to the correct position but is then reset back to the default position.
The final goal is to be able to put content in the text area and have the content in the iframe match the position in text area as it is being updated via `oninput`.

```js
function scrollMe() {
document.getElementById('iframeScroll').srcdoc = document.getElementById('wordMe').value;
document.getElementById('iframeScroll').contentWindow.document.documentElement.scrollTop = 1000;
document.getElementById('iframeScroll').contentWindow.document.documentElement.scrollLeft = 1000;

}
```

```html
<textarea oninput="scrollMe()" id="wordMe"></textarea>
<iframe id="iframeScroll" srcdoc=""></iframe>
```

Uncaught TypeError: 
Cannot set property 'scrollTop' of null at scrollMe at HTMLTextAreaElement.oninput

Answer (score 0):

```js
function scrollMe() {
document.getElementById('iframeScroll').srcdoc = document.getElementById('wordMe').value;
document.getElementById('iframeScroll').scrollTop = 1000;
document.getElementById('iframeScroll').scrollLeft = 1000;

}
```

```html
<textarea oninput="scrollMe()" id="wordMe"></textarea>
<iframe id="iframeScroll" srcdoc=""></iframe>
```

Comment: The scrollbar position remains unchanged from what I'm seeing.  The goal is to move it to 1000px when inputting content into textarea.